# Reuse or DuplicateExisting SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I work with a large organization in which various groups create and use their own SharePoint sites. One group has created a SharePoint calendar that is very elaborate for their own site, and our group would like to create and use one exactly like it. Is there a way to duplicate, reuse, or import an existing calendar app from another SharePoint site without having to recreate it from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **list template** to copy a list from one site to another:

1. Save the calendar list as a list template via `CALENDAR > List Settings > Save list as template`. Select **Include Content** if you want to carry the events as well.
2. When it is finished, navigate to `Site Settings > List templates` (or just click **list template gallery** on the page), select the list template you just created and download a copy to local drive.
3. Navigate to another site, go to `Site Settings > List templates` and then upload the list template copy.
4. Add the calendar list via `Site contents > New > App` > search for the list template and click on it.

[image]

Reference:
[How to copy a sharepoint calendar to another site.](http://jamesrong.com/how-to-copy-a-sharepoint-calendar-to-another-site/)